# How do I determine how an APK dependency is being used?

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I am somewhat new to React Native. When I analyze an APK in Android Studio, I can see that some packages are being included, but I can't determine how they are being used. What's the best way to debug something like this? For example, when I look at `classes.dex` I can see that there is a `com.facebook.common.time` package. Is there a way to trace that to its use within the source?

Comment: Maybe request a new feature here at [stackzy](https://github.com/theapache64/stackzy) ;) , A Compose Desktop app built for dependency analysis. Great piece of work by [theapache64](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4370279/sifar) !